# Increasing MAX UPLOAD limit for Word Press (I Tried it all)

Tags: php, lamp, wordpress

https://atlantisthemes.com/fix-upload_max_filesize/
I've tried everything on here and several more
whenever i go to wordpress and check new media upload limit , it says 2MB

I've restarted apache everytime i made a change and still nothing

htaccess changed, php.ini changed, wp-config file edited

and the functions thing under theme won't save, not sure where it is either

if anyone could solve this for me would be greatly appreciated as i have a high end theme waiting to be uploaded. thanks!
Sincerely Kevin K.

Also, i am the one that installed LAMP, self hosted server. Maybe that's the problem?

Also, I have tried editing the php.ini at two different locations already..

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, but since (i guess) you're running this on an ubuntu server, it's technically not off-topic.

Comment: hello neo the third, you seem to be very tech savy but still dont have any answer for me? yes i am running this on an ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have edit php.ini in wrong location.
Create in document root and open in browser this file, name it like info.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Find where php.ini located(from browser output), change or add lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: after editing, I needed to also run `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours, I went through almost all the posts but no luck. And finally resolved the issue with these steps. This might be weird solution but worked for me.

1. Find `php.ini` file in `/etc` folder  or `/` folder by running below cmd:

   ```
   grep -rl "post_max_size" | xargs ls -lrth
   ```

   Here I have used the post_max_size keyword to search the "php.ini" file in `/etc` folder ,but in some systems you can find this on `/var/www/html` or `/var/www/wordpress` folders.

   We have multiple posts on the internet as if the php.ini file is not present in the WordPress folder then you can create but in my case that doesn't work.
2. Edit the php.ini file and change the value like this.

   ```
   post_max_size = 100M   
   upload_max_filesize = 100M
   ```

   In the above you can set any value as per your requirement.
3. Restart the httpd or Nginx or apache and PHP service, or as per setup, you can restart the web service.

   For me httpd and php-fpm service restart worked in centos 8:

   ```
   service httpd restart
   service php-fpm restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to increase the wordpress upload limit - without success. According to phpinfo() there was only a memory limit of 512 MB. The media upload site within wordpress however showed me a upload limit of 64 MB. I was not abled to upload a file bigger than 64 MB.

**Solution:**
In the end I installed the wordpress plugin `Tuxedo Big File Uploads`. Now I have a upload limit of 988 GB. I was able to upload very big files.